# Node.js error chaining not propagating to calling function

Tags: node.js

I have a Nodejs cron job that runs every 5 seconds:

```
cron.schedule("*/5 * * * * * *", async function() {    //Every 5 seconds
    try{

        await cleanUpDatabase()
       
    }
    catch(err){
       console.log(err)
       console.trace(err.lineNumber)
    }
});

async function cleanUpDatabase(){
    let pool = await connection;

    pool.query(`SELECT * FROM table1`)
}
```

I do not have a table named table1 in my database. I want the second function to produce an error

But from my understanding of try catch block since the function that is calling the `cleanUpDatabase` function has catch statement it should catch the error even though there is no try catch on `cleanUpDatabase` function. However it does not catch it

In my express application I have a function that displays all unhandled rejection:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (error, p) => { //I added this so that I can console log the unhandled rejection and where it is coming from. Before this I would just get UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection without knowing which promise was not handled
    console.log('=== UNHANDLED REJECTION ==='); // Not good to have unhandled promise rejection in code. This will just help me locate it incase here is one
    console.dir(error.stack);
});
```

This function is catching the error. Which means that the error is not handled. The error that I am getting is:

> === UNHANDLED REJECTION === "RequestError: Invalid object name 'table1'.\n"

Why is the parent function not able to handle the error?

**Edit 1:**

Even this does not work. I'm really confused now

```
async function cleanUpDatabase(){
    try{
        let pool = await connection;
        pool.query(`SELECT * FROM table1`)
    }
    catch(err){
        throw err;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function cleanUpDatabase() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let pool = await connection;
        pool.query(`SELECT * FROM table1`);
        resolve();
    }).catch((error) => { 
        console.log(error); 
    });
}
```